# unable to execute hadoop command with php because of GCC 4.2.0 not found

Tags: php, hadoop, gcc

when i want to run my phpscript which is

```
$cmd = shell_exec('/usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop fs -ls /Output');
echo '$output';
```

i got this on my php error log:

```
Error: failed /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/i386/server/libjvm.so, because /opt/lampp/lib/libgcc_s.so.1: version `GCC_4.2.0' not found (required by /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6)
```

why is this happening exactly?
my ubuntu version is 12.04 LTS and my GCC version is 4.6.3.

Answer (score 0):

`/opt/lampp/lib/libgcc_s.so.1` comes from an older GCC versions.  Something probably set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to include the directory `/opt/lampp/lib`, thus overriding the system version of that library.

You might be able to fix this by deleting (or moving away) the `/opt/lampp/lib/libgcc_s.so.1` file, but you should check that no other libraries are overridden in the same way.

*Usually*, it should not affect the other application because the official `libgcc_s.so.1` library (as provided by upstream and most distributions) is very backwards-compatible, so using a newer version is always okay. However, the other application may have shipped a patched, non-official version `libgcc_s.so.1` with custom changes, in which case it would now break, but this seems unlikely.

Comment: it works!! thanks a lot. i thought i need to install the older version. is this method gonna do something to the other application other than hadoop?

Comment: I updated my answer.  For `libgcc_s.so.1` in particular, it should not cause problems.